# Removing newline with space character using sed or tr command in script tag in a file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, tr

This is my test file. In this file, there is a newline character after a script tag. I want to remove that character with space character. I want to write a shell script so that this kind of errors can be remove.

```
<html>
<head>
<script
type="text/javascript" sfsf="test" src="http://test.mydomain.com/test"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://test.com/public//test"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The output should be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" sfsf="test" src="http://test.mydomain.com/test"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://test.com/public//test"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

i find the solution my self

```
cat file | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/> \?/>\n/g'
```

Comment: please clarify how you want to replace this file ?

Comment: The solution you found by yourself, does not produce the desired output. it will delete empty lines, but I guess it's ok for you.

Comment: @Tiago: yes u r right . I didn't notice that ,thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `perl`:

```
perl -n0e 's/(script)(\s+)/$1 /g; print' file
```

or you can omit the "print" command if you use -p instead of -n:

```
perl -p0e 's/(script)(\s+)/$1 /g;' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` to remove newlines and carriage returns and strip spaces after script tag with `sed`.

`cat file | tr -d '\n' | td -d '\r' | sed 's#</script>[[:space:]]+##g'`

Comment: Feel free to replace `cat file | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\r'` by `tr -d '\n\r' < file`.

Comment: + 1 because i do feel :)

Comment: it will do like <scripttype="text/javascript" sfsf="test" src="http://test.mydomain.com/test"></script>

Comment: i see. then just replace the deletion in `tr -d ...` with its replacement command `tr '\r\n' ' ' `